# MySQL Skip Empty Strings Query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, csv, import

So I have an application set up to import a CSV file. It creates both a Data Table and a temporary sql table. The code reads the CSV and puts it into the Data Table and then bulk imports it into the temporary table, which as of now simply then copies it over to the production table. For my purposes I need it so that when the .csv file is imported and there are empty strings that they be skipped and not inserted or updated within the production database and only insert/update what is present in the csv(barring the empty strings of course).

So for example say the first time I go to import I just simply imported the following site info:

> PDW0033B50D3,Northeast office,246 Western Blvd

And then say later on I want to update the address of the location, so I reimport a csv file with just the necessary fields.

> PDW0033B50D3,,290 Western Blvd

Right now the code will put an empty string in the database for the second line when empty so Northeast office will turn into a blank/empty string in the database. How do I make it so that when there is an empty string in the csv it is skipped via my sql query?

Here is my code:

```
       public void btnBulkSite_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //Save File
        if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\" + FileUpLoad1.FileName);
            btnBulkSite.Text = "File Uploaded: " + FileUpLoad1.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            btnBulkSite.Text = "No File Uploaded.";
        }

            //Create Temporary Table

        string TmpTable = "CREATE TABLE #TMPBULK (SERVER_ID VARCHAR(13), SITE_NAME VARCHAR(50), SITE_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50))";
            //Create DataTable
        DataTable tblcsv = new DataTable();

        tblcsv.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SERVER_ID", typeof(string)));
        tblcsv.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SITE_NAME", typeof(string)));
        tblcsv.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SITE_ADDRESS", typeof(string)));



            //Read in CSV File
        System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.InputStream);

        string ReadCSV = stream.ReadToEnd();
        foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
                {
                tblcsv.Rows.Add();
                int count = 0;

                foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(','))
                {
                    tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

            //SQL CON
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["css"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            con2.Open();

            //Execute the command to make a temp table
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(TmpTable, con2);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (BulkOperation bulk = new BulkOperation(con2))

            {


                bulk.DestinationTableName = "#TMPBULK";

                bulk.BulkInsert(tblcsv);
            }

            //Copy Data from Temp Table to Prod Table
            string mergeSql = "merge into SITE_INFO as Target " +
              "using #TMPBULK as Source " +
              "on " +
              "Target.SERVER_ID=Source.SERVER_ID " +
              "and Target.SITE_NAME = Source.SITE_NAME " +
              "when matched then " +
              "update set Target.SITE_ADDRESS=Source.SITE_ADDRESS " +
              "when not matched then " +
              "insert (SERVER_ID,SITE_NAME,SITE_ADDRESS) values (Source.SERVER_ID,Source.SITE_NAME,Source.SITE_ADDRESS);";






            cmd.CommandText = mergeSql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "drop table #TMPBULK";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your SET from

```
update set Target.SITE_ADDRESS=Source.SITE_ADDRESS
```

to

```
update set Target.SITE_ADDRESS=IF(Source.SITE_ADDRESS='',Target.SITE_ADDRESS,Source.SITE_ADDRESS)
```

and similarly for SITE_NAME.